# Increase edge capacity under some consideration won't change max-flow

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I want to prove that if we have a graph G and and maximum flow in it F,then if we change each edge capacity under below considerations the max flow won't change:

$\forall e \in E, \qquad c^\prime(e) \geq c(e)$

$\forall e \in E,\qquad f(e) = c(e) \Rightarrow c^\prime(e) = c(e)$

I can understand it intuitively but i cannot find a mathematical proof for it,any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm?  If so, how would the residual network change if the capacities were increased?

Comment: @saulspatz the algorithm is not important, when the algorithm is finished we then do these modifications.

Comment: And then you run another round of the algorithm to find an augmenting path, right?  If the flow can be increased, the algorithm with says so.

Comment: @saulspatz no we don't want to run algorithm, i just wanna prove it by mathematics that it won't change

Comment: I am describing a mathematical proof.  Do you understand the Ford Fulkerson algorithm, and its proof?

Comment: @saulspatz yes but i cannot understand your point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively: Let $C$ be any minimum cut and let $f$ be a maximum flow. Then each edge in $C$ is at capacity. If you increase the capacity of any subset of any edge not in $C$, each edge by any nonnegative amount, then $C$ will still remain a cut with the same capacity, and furthermore, the capacity of any other cut, if it changes, will only increase. So the capacity of the minimum cut will not change. Furthermore, $f$ is still a feasible flow (make sure you see why), and as the capacity of the minimum cut hasb't changed, it follows that $f$ is still a maximum flow.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that we have a maximal flow $F$ in $G$.  Then there is no augmenting path in the network, for if there were, by the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, $F$ would not be maximal.

Now suppose the capacities are changed as described to give a new network $G'$.  Since no capacity decreases, $F$ is still a valid flow in $G'$.  Also, $F$ is maximal in $G'$ since the changes described do not create any augmenting paths.  Recall that a path is augmenting if and only if the smallest residual along the path is greater than zero.

More explicitly, consider an $S-T$ path $P$ in $G$.  Since this is not an augmenting path, there is some edge $e$ in $P$ with $c(e)=f(e)$.  Otherwise the residual in every edge in $P$ would be positive, and we could increase $F$ by $\min(\{c(e)-f(e)|e\in P\})$.  For any such $e$, $c'(e)=c(e)=f(e)$ so $P$ is not an augmenting path in $G'$.